# Is There A Way To Improve Performance Of Data Dictionary Model To Dict Appraoch?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am currently getting a bunch of records for formsets in my Django application with the method below...

```
    line_items = BudgetLineItem.objects.filter(budget_pk=dropdown)

    line_item_listofdicts = []
    for line_item in line_items:
        line_item_dict = model_to_dict(line_item)
        del line_item_dict['id']
        del line_item_dict['budget']
        del line_item_dict['archive_budget']
        del line_item_dict['new_budget']
        del line_item_dict['update_budget']
        line_item_listofdicts.append(line_item_dict)

    UpdateBudgetLineItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(UpdateBudget,
                                                        UpdateBudgetLineItem,
                                                        form=UpdateBudgetLineItemForm,
                                                        extra=len(line_item_listofdicts),
                                                        can_delete=True,
                                                        can_order=True)
```

The good news is that it works and does what I want it to.  However it's super slow.  It takes about 13 seconds to render the data back to my app.  Not optimal.  I've spent the morning trying to do various prefetches and select_relateds but nothing has worked to improve the time it takes to render these fields back to the screen.  The fields in question are largely DecimalFields and I've read that they can be a bit slower.  I'm trying to use this data as "input" to my formsets in a CreateView.  Again it works...but it's slow.  Any ideas on how to make this approach more performant?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of retreiving the models and deleting the fields you dont need, you could just query the models specifying only the list of fields you want
*using  the queryset `values(*args)` method which you specify the fields you need as str(s)*

And it will Automatically return it as a list dictionary with the specified fields
#taking your  code for example, it me assume you only need the **title** and **added_date** from your model

*Note just assuming your BudgetLineItem model has the fields title and added_date* then you code could be like

```
line_items = BudgetLineItem.objects.filter(budget_pk=dropdown).values('title', 'added_on') 

   
    UpdateBudgetLineItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(UpdateBudget,
                                                        UpdateBudgetLineItem,
                                                        form=UpdateBudgetLineItemForm,
                                                        extra=line_items.count(),
                                                        can_delete=True,
                                                        can_order=True)
```

**From you code you are doing operations that you dont need**

-Since it just the len of the items need you dont need to evaluate the query,  you could just call the `count` method of the queryset

-If there some peice od code that still needs to use your `line_item_listofdicts` variable then you could just replace it with the `line_items` as it is a list of dictionary containing only the fields you need,  instead of converting you model queryset to a list of of model instances and deleting the fields you don't need and again converting it to another list (these operations a expensive)

You could check out the document on [value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond!  Your suggestions make perfect sense.  I incorporated them...but unfortunately while they worked...they did not improve performance at all.  I am doing a significant amount of queries...I'm wondering if the problem is really there and not here.